# React / Redux: how to update one cell of a grid without re-rendering all the others

Tags: reactjs, optimization, reselect

I have a React / Redux app in which I draw a 2-dimensional grid. The grid data is in the Redux store, as an array of arrays. e.g. for a 3x2 grid it might be like this:

```
state.grid = [
[{value: 1},{value: 2}],
[{value: 0},{value: 1}],
[{value: 1},{value: 3}]
]
```

The user can click a grid square to change its value. As the grid can be large, I want to update only the cell that has been changed. But whatever I try, the entire grid is updated.

I'm using [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) with [re-reselect](https://github.com/toomuchdesign/re-reselect) to memoize the individual selectors, but I don't think it's working. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
GridCell.js:

class GridCell extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        const { valueObj } = this.props;
        return <span>valueObj.value</span>
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const { rowIndex, columnIndex } = ownProps;
    const valueObj = getValueCached(state, `${columnIndex}_${rowIndex}`);
console.log('which cell', `${columnIndex}_${rowIndex}`);

    return {valueObj};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GridCell);
```

There is also a parent component which draws the grid of GridCells, passing to each one its columnIndex and rowIndex as props:

```
class MyGrid extends PureComponent {
    const columns = 3;
    const rows = 2;

    render() {
        columns.map((column) => {
            rows.map((row) => {
                <GridCell
                    columnIndex={column}
                    rowIndex={row}
                />
        }
}
```

and in my Redux store:

```
import createCachedSelector from 're-reselect';

export const getValueFromCache = (state, identifier) => {
    const identifiers = identifier.split('_');

    return state.grid[identifiers[0]][identifiers[1]];
};

export const getValueCached = createCachedSelector(
  getValueFromCache,

  // resultFunc
  (value) => value,
)(
  // re-reselect keySelector (receives selectors' arguments)
  // Use "columnIndex_rowIndex" as cacheKey
  // re-reselect only accepts string as cacheKey
  (_state_, identifier) => identifier
);
```

When the user clicks a grid square, the "which cell" log in the mapStateToProps function is written to the console for every grid cell.

Edit: I'm using [updeep](https://github.com/substantial/updeep) inside my reducer to update the values, something like this:

```
case UPDATE_GRID_CELL: {
    { newValue } = action.payload;
    return updeep({
        'grid': { [columnIndex]: { [rowIndex]: newValue } },
state);
}
```

I have also tried getting the value as a simple prop with connect:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const { rowIndex, columnIndex } = ownProps;

    return {state.grid[columnIndex][rowIndex].value};
}
```

and I've put a check in to see if any props or state have changed:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        console.log('componentWillUpdate');
        console.log('new', JSON.stringify(this.props));
        console.log('old', JSON.stringify(prevProps));
        console.log('changed props', JSON.stringify(this.props) !== JSON.stringify(prevProps));

        console.log('state');
        console.log('new', JSON.stringify(this.state));
        console.log('old', JSON.stringify(prevState));
        console.log('changed state', JSON.stringify(this.state) !== JSON.stringify(prevState));
    }
```

This logs false, yet the render() method runs, as shown by a console log. I'm puzzled because I thought the point of pureComponent is that it only renders if its state or props have changed?

I expected the memoization to provide the same values for the unaffected cells, and for this to not trigger a component update. But I must be missing something.

I don't know how to test whether the memoization is working. If I put a console.log in getValueCached(), it writes for every cell but I don't know whether it would do that anyway...?

Is there any way to prevent every grid cell component from updating when a single value is changed? Thank you for any suggestions.

Edit: from the comments / answer and further investigation, it seems the re-renders are caused by an array prop. I've created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59641706/react-redux-pure-component-with-an-array-property-re-renders-when-the-array) that illustrates this with a minimal sandbox example.

Comment: Why not connect instead connect `MyGrid` and instead just pass primitive values to `GridCell` components as simple props? I'd say wrapping every `GridCell` in a `connect()` is the key issue here.

Comment: Can you show us, how you update the values?

Comment: sometimes redux is too "complex" and does not let you do simple things. Maybe https://github.com/aralroca/fragmented-store helps you, thinking that if you update a field in your store, only the components that use that particular field are re-rendered and not the rest of the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missunderstand the mapStateToProps function.
It will be called for every redux state update and it has to figure out, if the values for that changed. So it has to call every mapStateToProps for each cell.

That does not mean, though, that it rerenders that component.
If the previous and current return values of mapStateToProps are the same, the update will be aborted.

So it is correct that the mapStateToProps  is called. Check if the cells are actually rerendered. You can also remove the getValueCached wrapper and access the grid directly with `state.grid[identifiers[0]][identifiers[1]]`. This will be faster than the cached version since its just a direct access. And you do not get any benefit from the cached version, since its not a heavy computation.

It might even be faster to connect the highest component and jsut let it rerender if needed. Another option is to use react-window to only render the current visible grid items, which will greatly improve your performance.

Comment: Thanks. A console.log in the render() method of the grid cell shows that each cell is re-rendering, but I don't know why because it looks to me that the component props, and the return of MapStateToProps, have not changed.

Comment: Can you reproduce that in a sandbox

Comment: Also how do you update the grid values in the store?

Comment: My actual code has a lot more to it, including a couple of array properties. Those however have not changed, only the simple 'value' prop.

Comment: I created a new question with a sandbox because the problem seems to be about array props, not memoization: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59641706/react-redux-pure-component-with-an-array-property-re-renders-when-the-array